# Why $T_{A}M(n) = M(n)$ and why $T_{f(A)}S(n) = S(n)$ and why $M(n)$ & $S(n)$ are manifolds. (Guillemin & Pollack p.23)

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology, tangent-spaces

Why $T_{A}M(n) = M(n)$ and why $T_{f(A)}S(n) = S(n)$ and why $M(n)$ & $S(n)$ are manifolds?

$M(n)$ is the space of all $n x n$ matrices and $S(n)$ is the space of all $n x n$ symmetric matrices.

A manifold definition is: a subset $X$ of some ambient euclidean space $R^{N}$ is a k-dimensional manifold if it is locally diffeomorphic to $R^k$.

Could anyone clarify the above questions for me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a vector space $V$, for any element $v\in V$, we always have $T_vV = V$. The space $M(n)$ of matrices is a vector space, and $S(n)$ is a vector subspace.

Comment: Is there a proof of this fact?

Comment: Sure: You have a global parametrization $\phi\colon \Bbb R^n\to V$ when $V$ is $n$-dimensional, and $T_vV = \text{im}(d\phi_a)$ when $\phi(a)=v$. But $\phi$ is a vector space isomorphism. You finish.

Comment: What about the rest of my questions?

Comment: I already answered them. :)

Comment: Why they are manifolds?

Comment: As I said, any vector space is a manifold because you have a global parametrization. You need to understand the definitions!

Comment: Why I have a global parametrization and what is it?

Comment: What does it mean to say a vector space is $n$-dimensional?